# Custom list rendering in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I need to display items as couples. Like this for example:

```
Template.container.couples = function() {
    var items = Items.find({}, {sort: {sort_field: 1}}).fetch();
    var couples = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        couples.push({
            itemA: items[i],
            itemB: items[i + 1]
        });
        i++;
    }
    return couples;
};

<template name="container">
   <ul>
       {{#each couples}}
           <li>
               <p class="item-a">{{>item itemA}}</p>
               <span>|</span>
               <p class="item-b">{{>item itemB}}</p>
           </li>
       {{/each}}
   <ul>
</template>

<template name="item">
    <strong>{{title}}</strong>
</template>
```

Items look like:

```
{
   sort_field: 1,
   title: 'Item 1',
   type: 'A'
},
{
   sort_field: 2,
   title: 'Item 2',
   type: 'B'
},
{
   sort_field: 3,
   title: 'Item 3',
   type: 'A'
},
{
   sort_field: 4,
   title: 'Item 4',
   type: 'B'
},
{
   sort_field: 5,
   title: 'Item 5',
   type: 'A'
}
```

This code works good, but when I update title for one of items then all items rerender.

How to fix it? How to create this kind of layout with reactivity?

Comment: Oh didn't see you used `fetch()` there, have you considered using transform to join the couples up? Let me know if the below works so I can edit it

Comment: Transform? Did you mean find all items of type A then with transform find for each of them corresponding item of type B?

Answer (score 0):

As of Meteor 0.8.0, [Meteor will automagically only re-render content that changes.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v080-2014-mar-27)